# JVM http proxy in windows cmd

Tags: java, windows, proxy, jvm, cmd

I am using a java application which requires internet. But I have internet through proxy so application doesn't work. I am looking for a way to enable proxy in JVM (note i can't change it by code , i doesn't have source code). Kindly let me know how i can do that through command prompt on windows.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800 yourprogramhere
```

Comment: I know this works if the application is using the JVM's URLConnection classes.  Does this work if the client application is using Apache HttpClient?

Comment: Not sure, but give it a try

Comment: But it does work. When i type it, cmd shows java help window (i.e. what we get by typing "java help" in cmd) .